# How can I return a filename to Jquery from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am saving a canvas image to a .png file using the following code:

jQuery:

```
$(".save").click(function () {
    var canvas = $("#standard_canvas");
    var src = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            data: src
        },
        complete: function (data, status) {
            if (status == 'success') {
                alert("image saved!")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[save.php]

```
<?php
$based64Image = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ',') + 1);
$image        = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($based64Image));
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

$fileName = '';
if ($image != false)
  {
    $fileName = 'image/designs/' . time() . '.png';
    if (!imagepng($image, $fileName))
      {
        //          fail;
      }
  }
else
  {
    //          fail;
  }

?>
```

What I would like to do is have the new filename passed back to my ajax call so that I can use it to populate a hidden input field (which I can then save along with a customer order). Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file you could create a json response containing your filename

```
  $data['filename'] = $fileName;
  echo json_encode($data);
```

And read it out in your ajax response

```
$(".save").click(function () {
    var canvas = $("#standard_canvas");
    var src = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
     $.ajax({
         url: 'save.php',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
             data: src
         },
         success: function (data, status) {
             if (status == 'success') {
                 alert("image saved!")
                 var filename = data.filename //<--------
             }
         }
     });
});
```

EDIT:
(which I can then save along with a customer order)

A better practice would be storing the filename in a session variable on the server side.
This prevents the client form changing the filename (even if it's in a hidden field)

Comment: For some reason, this always returns an undefined object when i try to do an 'alert(filename)' .. however, when I put it in a success callback rather than complete, it seemed to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add following line in image upload success part :

```
echo $filename
```

Then in your ajax call,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: src
    },
    complete: function (data, status) {
        if (status == 'success') {
            alert("image saved!");
            alert("Filename : "+data);
            // Do anything with the file name here
        }
    }
});
```

This should do it for you.